# Getting multiple results in almost identical queries

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have two very similar queries in FNH, acting on similar classes, Project and Foo.
Foo is simply a new local class derived from Project.  Its classMap is derived from Project's classMap as well.

```
    public class Foo:pcm.Domain.Project { }
    public class FooMap : pcm.Mappings.ProjectMapBase<Foo> { }
```

Here are my queries, using the same session:

```
        var list = session.Query<Project>()
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();

        var list2 = session.Query<foo>()
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();

        Assert.Equal(list.Count(),list2.Count());
```

The assertion fails because list has 30 elements, and list2 has 10.  There are indeed only 10 projects.

**Edit**: Here are the mappings for the base, which sits in its own DLL.

```
public class ProjectBaseMapTemplate<T> : ClassMap<T> where T: ProjectBase
{
    public ProjectBaseMapTemplate()
    {
        Table("proj");
        Id(x => x.MasterKey, "master_key");
        Map(x => x.ProjectName).Column("project_name");
        Map(x => x.ProjectTitle, "project_title");
    }
}
public class ProjectBaseMap : ProjectBaseMapTemplate<ProjectBase> { }
```

Here are the derived class, which sit in another DLL.  This separation of classes into DLLs is fundamentally important to how I need to use FNH.

```
    public class Foo:pcm.Domain.ProjectBase 
    {
            public virtual int ProjectState{ get; set; }
    }
    public class FooMap : pcm.Mappings.ProjectBaseMapTemplate<Foo> 
    {
        public FooMap()
        {
            Map(x=> x.ProjectState).Column("project_state");
        }
    }
```

**Update** Here is the ProjectBase

```
public class ProjectBase
{
    public virtual string MasterKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post you mappings ? I would have said that is because the derived class has a fetch="join" one-to-many relationship. And would have said to replace this fetch="join" with fetch="select". But as it is the base class  which produces more elements, I'm puzzled :-)

Comment: No problem I updated the post with more info.

Comment: I don't see the Project class (basic one ?) Shouldn't it be public FooMap():base(){....}

Comment: ok, I added that too now.

Comment: Is CompanyList Mapped ? lazy-loaded or join loaded ? I'd guess the number of (project->company) relationships + the number of projects without company equals 30

Comment: I removed that- not relevant.  just working on one and only one table here.

Comment: last idea I have : I notice the lack of a discriminator column. If you add another subsclass, do you get 40 results in the Project list ?

Comment: I find that debug step number 1 is usually: Use the log or configuration property show_sql to look at the generated SQL for both queries - it will probably tell you what's is happening.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Take(10)` function
The Underlying select all query will be run based on your RDBMS functionality 
Then top 10 result will be returned (**paging**)

Since you don't use an **ORDER BY** expression, same queries will result different in multiple executions due to paging and RDBMS functionality.

Hope be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this:

> (10) polymorphism (optional, defaults to implicit): Determines whether implicit or explicit query polymorphism is used.
>
> Implicit polymorphism means that instances of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names any superclass or implemented interface
>   or the class and that instances of any subclass of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names the class itself. Explicit polymorphism
>   means that class instances will be returned only be queries that
>   explicitly name that class and that queries that name the class will
>   return only instances of subclasses mapped inside this 
>   declaration as a  or . For most purposes
>   the default, polymorphism="implicit", is appropriate. Explicit
>   polymorphism is useful when two different classes are mapped to the
>   same table (this allows a "lightweight" class that contains a subset
>   of the table columns).

So you would fix your mappings by using: `Polymorphism.Explicit();`

Ex.

```
public class FooMap : pcm.Mappings.ProjectBaseMapTemplate<Foo> 
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Polymorphism.Explicit();
        Map(x=> x.ProjectState).Column("project_state");
    }
}
```